# Header content higher than header heigth

Tags: header-footer, boxes

**Edited:** based on the discussion below I created an interactive file to help people to understand the margins. I'd like to get your opinion about that.

You can access it here: [Geogebra file to configure margins on LaTeX](http://db.tt/VBXarHhq) (tested on Chromium).

I hope you enjoy it.

---

I know that there are many commands to adjust the size of margins, text width and so on. But I'm not able to understand what happens with the header and body when we insert some box on the header that is higher than the value of header height.

So I drew the image below and I'd like to know which one describes the behavior.

The green box is the higher box and the blue one is a box which fits inside the header area.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The heading is pushed down and under-prints the body:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{\rule{1cm}{2cm}\dotfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
\clearpage

\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{\rule{1cm}{.2cm}\dotfill}
\makeatother

bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but those black rules are not aligned by their tops. So what is the rule to determine how much the head will go down?

Comment: I discovered that the upper edge of the header box is the line used to align the rules. So, my second figure is the right answer. Is it true?

Comment: @Sigure yes, as far as I understand the pictures and what LaTeX is doing here.

Comment: So, finally I'm almost finishing my work and understand the layout page. The strange part is the footer. Following this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout we see that `\footskip` controls the space between the bottom of body box and the bottom of the footer box. Great. But if we use an enough negative value to the skip the footer box touches the body box but does not go up, that is, the top of footer box is aligned with the bottom of the body box. This is not what the package `layout` shows.

Comment: Also, what is the height of the footer box? Is it not like the header box?